# jQuery click() function inside each()

Tags: jquery

Can anyone please help me with this bit of code.I do not understand what is wrong and why it's not performing. Thanks.

```js
var i = 0;
$('.course-testimonial-wrapper .testimonial-content-text').each(function() {
  // console.log(i);

  $(this).attr('id', 'testimonial-' + i);
  $(this).append('<div class="description-overlay" id="d-over-' + i + '"></div>');
  $(this).after('<div><button class="btn green show-more-' + i + ' shadow-0 p-0 medium" style="font-size: 14px;">Mostra di più <i class="fi-rr-angle-small-down"></i></button></div>');

  $('.show-more-' + i + '').click(function() {
    $('#testimonial-' + i + '').toggleClass('expand');
    $('#d-over-' + i + '').toggleClass('d-none');

    if ($('#testimonial-' + i + '').hasClass('expand')) {
      $('.show-more-' + i + '').html('Mostra di meno <i class="fi-rr-angle-small-up"></i>');
    } else {
      $('.show-more-' + i + '').html('Mostra di più <i class="fi-rr-angle-small-down"></i>');
    }
  })
  i++;
})
```

Comment: What do you mean by it is "not performing"? See how to create a [minimal, concrete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: not performing i mean not working sorry

Comment: The click() function inside the each() function is not working.

Comment: Do more logging, like `$('.show-more-' + i + '').length` or such

Comment: Do some basic debugging. Does the callback passed to `.each()` actually run? If so, does the selector you're trying to bind the click event to (`$('.show-more-' + i + '')`) actually find an element? Etc.

Comment: Yep, the each() function works properly, add all the stuff with all method .attr(), .append() and .after() only .click() is not working

Comment: Do you get the click event?  ie if you add an alert/console.log as the first line, does it fire?  "not working" is extremely unhelpful, see https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `i` to make it more dynamic. You could do it like this.

```
$('.show-more').click(function() {
  var testimonial = $(this).parent().prev();
  testimonial.toggleClass('expand');
  testimonial.find('.description-overlay').toggleClass('d-none');

  if (testimonial.hasClass('expand')) {
    $(this).html('Mostra di meno <i class="fi-rr-angle-small-up"></i>');
  } else {
    $(this).html('Mostra di più <i class="fi-rr-angle-small-down"></i>');
  }
})
```

**Demo**

```js
$('.testimonial-content-text').each(function(i, x) {
  // console.log(i);
  $(this).attr('id', 'testimonial-' + i);
  $(this).append('<div class="description-overlay" id="d-over-' + i + '"></div>');
  $(this).after('<div><button class="btn green show-more shadow-0 p-0 medium" style="font-size: 14px;">Mostra di più <i class="fi-rr-angle-small-down"></i></button></div>');


})

$('.show-more').click(function() {
  var testimonial = $(this).parent().prev();
  testimonial.toggleClass('expand');
  testimonial.find('.description-overlay').toggleClass('d-none');

  if (testimonial.hasClass('expand')) {
    $(this).html('Mostra di meno <i class="fi-rr-angle-small-up"></i>');
  } else {
    $(this).html('Mostra di più <i class="fi-rr-angle-small-down"></i>');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="testimonial-content-text">test1</div>
<div class="testimonial-content-text">test2</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much...you made my day :-)

Comment: @ross80 No problem, happy to help

Comment: @ross80 If this answers you question correctly please accept the answer (check mark to the left) so we can see you don't need help anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is to do with the scope of the `i` variable. When your loop completes `i` will be the final value it was set to in the iteration. You can fix this with a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/750506/519413).

*However* a far better approach is to get rid of the unnecessary incremental `id` and `class` attributes, and use common class names instead. Then you can traverse the DOM to find the related elements and update them as required, all within a single delegated event handler which is created once outside the loop. Try this:

```js
$('.course-testimonial-wrapper .testimonial-content-text').each(function() {
  $(this).append('<div class="description-overlay">Description overlay...</div>');
  $(this).after('<div><button class="btn green show-more shadow-0 p-0 medium">Mostra di più <i class="fi-rr-angle-small-down"></i></button></div>');
});

$('.course-testimonial-wrapper').on('click', '.show-more', function() {
  let $btn = $(this);
  let $content = $btn.closest('.course-testimonial-wrapper').find('.testimonial-content-text').toggleClass('expand');
  $content.find('.description-overlay').toggleClass('d-none');

  if ($content.hasClass('expand')) {
    $btn.html('Mostra di meno <i class="fi-rr-angle-small-up"></i>');
  } else {
    $btn.html('Mostra di più <i class="fi-rr-angle-small-down"></i>');
  }
});
```

```css
.show-more {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="course-testimonial-wrapper">
  <div class="testimonial-content-text"></div>
</div>
```